# Unity 5.1.1 skips "Input.GetKeyDown" line sometimes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I use Unity 5.1.1 on a Win 64 bit machine, more than capable to run what i'm creating of games. In the making of a 2D sidescroller, i found my character sometimes doesn't jump when prompted. Here is the code:

```
public float speed;
public float MomentAcc;
private float moveVertical;

private float score;
private float scoreP;

public GameObject wallRight;
public GUIText scoreText;
public bool touching;

void Start() {
    MomentAcc = 10;
    score = 0;

}

    //Jump limiter 
    void OnCollisionStay2D() {

    touching = true;            
}

    void OnCollisionExit2D() {

    touching = false;
}


    void Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && touching == true || Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began && touching == true) {

        moveVertical = 29;

    } else {

        moveVertical = 0;

    }

}

    void FixedUpdate () {


        scoreP = GameObject.Find ("Ball").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().position.x + 11;

        if(scoreP > score) {

        score = score + 10;

        }   

            UpdateScore ();

                if(GetComponent<Death>().startGame == true) {



            float moveHorizontal = 5;


            Vector2 forward = new Vector2 (moveHorizontal, 0);
            Vector2 jump    = new Vector2 (0, moveVertical);


            //Maxspeed limit

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (moveVertical * jump);


            speed = moveHorizontal * MomentAcc * Time.deltaTime * 5;



                if (GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity.x < 7.000000) {


                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (Vector2.right * speed);




                    if(GameObject.Find ("wallRight").GetComponent<wallRightScript>().wallJumpRight == true) {

                    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (-420, 300));


                    } 

                    if(GameObject.Find ("wallLeft").GetComponent<wallLeftScript>().wallJumpLeft == true) {

                        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2(420, 150));

                    } 

                }   




        }
    }



    void UpdateScore() {

        scoreText.text = "Score: " + (score );

    }
```

}

(Sidenote: wallLeft/wallRight are for walljumping)

Comment: Please take the time to format your code so that people who want to help you will find it easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem!

you are using `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && touching == true` in this case your jump is dependent on `touching` variable which can be false at the time when you press the "W" key. You are using `rigidbody` you cannot expect it to always colliding with ground when it is being dragged in horizontal. So you may need to change your implementation for ground check.

[This Tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/2d/2d-controllers) is good for learning about 2D character.

And one more advice! try to store reference of objects/components in some variables to access them easily. Using `GetComponent<>`/`GameObject.Find()` in `Update()/FixedUpdate()` is not efficient so not a good practice.